# How to display HeaderedItemsControl Items As Column

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Im Writting a Costum DataGridView Using HeaderedItemsControl Class, And i Want To Put The Items Of My Controls Aligned As Column Like This:

Good

[image]

And Not As Actually Appear:

Actually

[image]

That´s My XAML Code:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:DataGridView}">
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Background="Red" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:DataGridView}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"/>
                    <ItemsPresenter Grid.Row="1"/>

                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Thanks For Read It

Comment: Is there some point to doing it this way I may be missing? Why not just use an actual DataGrid with normal headers/columns?

Comment: . Because DataGrid Is Not Necessary In My Case, ListView Have Some Bugs That Is More Hard To Solve Then Make It And i Relly Want To Costumize My Own DataGridView To Get More Control Of My Control, i Just Want To Align It As a Column. How Can i Make It?

Comment: Fair enough, I figured the use case could probably benefit from the other stuff you could do with DataGrid. Except if that doesn't work for ya, then why not just use the [HeaderedItemsControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.headereditemscontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? I mean right now, see in your ItemsPanel Orientation=Horizontal? Yea that's going to keep doing that to your Items. I mean I could show you how to do this way but there's other things already easy to use for it?